# Unable to resolve 'AppCompatPreferenceActivity' in SettingsActivity

Tags: java, android, preferences

I have an AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java. But it shows an error in this

`public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity`
It says it couldn't resolve 'AppCompatPreferenceActivity'.
[image]

And it seems like I am the only one with this problem. Any idea?

Error:(21, 39) error: cannot find symbol class AppCompatPreferenceActivity

Comment: your question is not clear make it clear!

Comment: Your class isn't in the same package, and you're not  importing it

Comment: it worked, it was created in the wrong place by mistake. How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 5):

AppCompatPreferenceActivity does not existing in google support libary,

you should create a class with same name and use this source:

```
public abstract class AppCompatPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();
    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
}

public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
    getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    getDelegate().onPostResume();
}

@Override
protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
    super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
    getDelegate().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getDelegate().onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getDelegate().onDestroy();
}

public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
    getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
    if (mDelegate == null) {
        mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
    }
    return mDelegate;
}

}
```

Comment: I do have a similar class like you mentioned. But the couldn't be resolved in SettingsActivity.

Comment: Create a new project and test it, what's the result?

Comment: It does exist in the samples. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/58bf5b99e6132332afb8b44b4c8cedf5756ad464/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java